# After submit, input text disappears and reload the page(AJAX)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Why my page reloads even I used ajax to it and it also disappears my input text after clicking the submit button. I already used show to solve it but it doesn't work.

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<span id="namenotif" style="color:red;"> <span>
<br>
<input type="text" name="price" id="price">
 <span id="pricenotif" style="color:red;"> <span>


<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="save"><br>
</form>


<script>  
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on("click","#save",function(){
var name = $("#name").val();
var price = $("#price").val();
if(name==""){
  $("#namenotif").html("Enter a name");
  $("#name").show("fast");
     $("#save").show("fast");
}
else if(price==""){
   $("#pricenotif").html("Enter a price");
   $("#price").show("fast");
           $("#save").show("fast");
 }else{
  $.ajax({
    url:"addproduct.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:{name:name,price:price}, 
    success:function(data){
      alert("Successful");
       }
      });
     }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: use type button instead of submit for button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery.ajax reloads page instead of performing ajax request in Safari on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683896/jquery-ajax-reloads-page-instead-of-performing-ajax-request-in-safari-on-ios)

Comment: I cant understand why you not separe the save and validation actions would help you to clear the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its because of type="submit"

**Use**

```
<input type="button" name="submit" id="save"><br>
```

**Or**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0) id="save">
```

**or**

jquery's `preventDefault();`

Comment: should I include post in a form tag and action even I used ajax for it?

Comment: no need to include action or method in form tag when you submit data using ajax.

Comment: I have observed that when I submit the form it only required one field in a time. I think it's because of the condition I used.

Answer (score 0):

add return false to end of function, that handle click event

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

1. Change the button `type='submit'` to `type='button'`

or ( and preferably )

2. Change the event listener to listen for the form's `onSumbit` event then call `event.preventDefault` or in jQuery, I think you just do `return false` in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

The form is being submitted I think, because it is the default behavior of submit button to submit the form, no matter if you used ajax or not. so you can prevent the default behavior by simple adding a code in jquery. Modify the code like this:

```
$(document).on("click","#save",function(e){
e.preventDefault();

...............
```

Rest of the codes can remain same. so only prevent the default action, it should work.