# After every AJAX call the page reloads

Tags: javascript, ajax

My page always reloads after every ajax call,

I have tried to take the following measure,

I have turned the button type to button,

I have used event.preventDefault()

Have also tried event.stopPropagation();

The following is my app.js

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('#importImg').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        if ($('#image')[0].files[0] != null) {
            $('#loading')[0].style.display = '';
            var file = $('#image')[0].files[0];
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', file);
            console.log(formData);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: (data) => {
                    var div = document.getElementById("content");
                    var image = document.createElement("img");
                    image.src = data;
                    image.setAttribute("class", "img-site");
                    div.appendChild(image);
                    $('#loading')[0].style.display = 'none';
                },
                error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    $('#loading')[0].style.display = 'none';
                }
            })
        } else {
            alert('Choose a file first!');
        }
    })
})
```

This is my html:

```
   <div class="addimg" style="margin-top: 5rem;">
    <input type="file" class="btn btn-primary" name="image" id="image"> 
    <button id="importImg" class="btn btn-danger">Upload</button><span><img style="width: 25px; margin-left: 5px; display: none" id="loading" src="200.gif" alt=""></span>
   </div>
```

Thank you In Advance!

Comment: who is calling this function

Comment: is the button inside a form element?

Comment: @GSP KS No It is not under form

Comment: @brk No one calls the fuction but it is binded to the button through event listener

Comment: then can you see if it redirects even without the ajax call. Remove only the ajax call codes and run it.

Comment: Can you explicitly add type="button" to your button and try.

Comment: @GSPKS Without AJAX call it doesn't redirect!

Comment: @MukeshKeshu Yes I have tried doing that, But not effect!

Comment: @mechanical_coder Can you add a return false and check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683896/jquery-ajax-reloads-page-instead-of-performing-ajax-request-in-safari-on-ios

Answer (score 0):

Try following JS:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('#importImg').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        if ($('#image')[0].files[0] != null) {
            $('#loading')[0].style.display = '';
            var file = $('#image')[0].files[0];
            var formData = new FormData(event.target);
            formData.append('file', file);
            console.log(formData);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: (data) => {
                    var div = document.getElementById("content");
                    var image = document.createElement("img");
                    image.src = data;
                    image.setAttribute("class", "img-site");
                    div.appendChild(image);
                    $('#loading')[0].style.display = 'none';
                },
                error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    $('#loading')[0].style.display = 'none';
                }
            })
        } else {
            alert('Choose a file first!');
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

add type="button" and return false from on click handler

Comment: It still does reload!

Comment: This answer needs more detail, and a proper code example.